# JSX ES6 add + 1 to tagged template string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have the following ES6 tagged template string with back-ticks and ${expr}:

```
`{ Some number is ${someNumber} }`
```

The variable `someNumber` is 30 and the string outputs `Some number is 30`

How can I add 1 to `someNumber` to get 31?

I tried:

```
`{ Some number is ${someNumber + 1} }`
```

But get `The number is 301`

Also

```
`{ Some number is ${someNumber} + 1}`
```

getting: `The number is 30 + 1`

I'm trying to get `Some number is 31`

Comment: `someNumber` is **not** a number. It's a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
`{ The number is ${parseInt(someNumber) + 1} }`
```

Answer (score 4):

`someNumber` is probably a string, convert it to a number (I've used the plus operator) before adding 1:

```js
const someNumber = '30';

const str = `{ The number is ${+someNumber + 1} }`;

console.log(str);
```

Comment: @CyberJ odd. This code works in Node 10 and Chrome 60.